# Monotouch Storyboard with with xib-less view controllers

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard, xib

I currently have monotouch project that uses a combination of a Storyboard and some xib-less (ViewControllers that don't have a corresponding xib or reference in the Storyboard) controllers (eg. Monotouch.Dialog).

Everything works well calling out from the Storyboard ViewControllers to the xib-less ones.  The problem I have is when I need to call from a xib-less ViewController back into a Storyboard ViewController.

Example flow:

- Storyboard

  - TabViewController

    - FirstViewController DialogViewController (not in Storyboard/xib-less)

      - AnotherViewController

The problem is when loading the AnotherViewController eg.

```
var avc = new AnotherViewController();
avc.Person = person
_dvc.ActivateController(avc);
```

I've had to create an empty constructor on the AnotherViewController to make this possible.  This view then loads, but is just an empty UIViewController (not the one in my Storyboard).  I can't setup a Segue between the MT.Dialog with the AnotherViewController in Interface Builder because the DialogViewController is created programmatically.

The workaround atm is to forget AnotherViewController in the Storyboard altogether and just programmatically create that one too - but it's a real shame that I can't combine/mix the Storyboard views with programmatic ones.

Any tips (or monotouch C# snippets) would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly : you want to pop your `AnotherViewController` - which is designed with IB in your storyboard - from a programmatically designed view controller, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller from `Storyboard`, just add `identifier` to it (in Storyboard) and then do:

```
YourController *c = 
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];
```

don't forget to initialize your instances in `viewDidLoad`, because `initWithNibName` will be never called